# ¿Cómo puedo desarrollar la opción de cambiar idioma usando como framework Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Buenas tardes, estoy maquetando un sítio web con Bootstrap, sin embargo, no consigo como desarrollarle la opción para cambiar a dos idiomas.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. ¿Podrías añadir más información a la Pregunta? _"Qué has intentado"_, como, código de ejemplo.  De esta manera se te podrá brindar una mejor respuesta.
Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo las [directrices de calidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Como verás SO.es no es un sustituto de Google; la investigación y los intentos van por tu cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, por los momentos no he intentado nada en relación al código porque es primera vez que úso bootstrap, y la verdad no soy experta en el desarrollo, que me podrías recomendar?

Sólo tengo el diseño desarrollado con  css, html5 y algunas funcionalidades en jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap no tiene que ver nada con tener un sitio web multi-idiomas. Hay varias maneras, normalmente se hace con lenguaje del lado del servidor, como puede ser `PHP`.

Aquí te dejo una demostración como se puede realizar una web multi-idiomas con `CSS` y un poco de JS:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
                 
  var lang = $(this).data('lang'); 
    
  $('html').prop('lang', lang);
    
});
```

```css
.es, .de, .en { display: none; }

.es:lang(es) {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}

.de:lang(de) {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
}

.en:lang(en) {
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <p class="es">Hola</p>
  <p class="de">Hallo</p>
  <p class="en">Hello</p>
  
  <!-- Para cambiar el idioma -->
  <button data-lang="es">Español</button>
  <button data-lang="de">Deutsch</button>
  <button data-lang="en">English</button>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El funcionamiento es simple, se elige el idioma según el atributo `lang` en `<html>`, el cual lo cambiamos con `JS`, luego te recomiendo de guardar esa selección con una `cookie` para memorizarlo.

[+ Info Cookies-en-javascript](https://cybmeta.com/cookies-en-javascript)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad, perdona quizás mi escaso conocimiento es que estoy aprendiendo,  si deseo que el cambio de idioma sea cuando de clip en un boton, como puedo agregar el evento?. mil gracias

Comment: @ultrasonico - Te he dejado otro ejemplo en _Mostrar fragmento de código_ para hacer lo con un `button`.. luego el valor elegido tendrías que guardarlo en una `cookie` cual te he dejado una referencia para que lo estudies. Si tienes más problemas sobre eso... te sugiero que habrás un nuevo post en cuando lo hayas probado y tengas problemas al respecto... suerte y saludos