# Como hacer una página multi idioma?

Tags: javascript, html5, json, xml, web

Necesito hacer una página web en HTML5/CSS3/JS con soporte en Español e Ingles (ES/EN). 
¿Conocen opciones de hacer el sitio en ambos idiomas sin tener que recurrir a hacer 2 páginas?

Sugerencias? Xml, Json o algo que conozcan?

Comment: Hola Carlos, hay muchas formas. En primer lugar debes elegir el tipo de app (SPA/SSR), el framework y la plataforma del servidor. Sin esa estas decisiones la pregunta es inmensamente amplia. Intenta limitar el scope de la pregunta, de modo que aunque sea extensa, pueda contestarse.

Comment: [En esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47407/6491) he dejado un ejemplo como hacerlo con un poco de `CSS` y `JS`...

Answer (score 3):

Los mensajes son del lado del servidor. En general en cualquier framework puedes usar la localización. basicamente tienes tus mensajes en diferentes idiomas y lo configuras segun desde donde se ve el sitio.

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /es
            messages.php

//lang/en/messages.php
<?php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
];

//lang/es/messages.php
<?php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Bienvenido a nuestra aplicación'
];
```

Ahora bien, si tambien queremos mostrar contenido mas amplio como htmls extensos puedes usar tecnologia como la del [Traductor de sitios de google](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=es). No la use y no la conozco pero tengo una nocion de lo que hace. creo que combinando estas cosas puedes llegar a lo que buscas.